# Are there any good client-side stock charting libraries out there?

Tags: javascript, charts, stockquotes

I would like to display interactive financial stock charts on a website, something like Google or Yahoo finance.  I saw some recommendations on this thread [looking for stock charting component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611704/looking-for-stock-charting-component)  but many of the suggestions are commercial, or require silverlight to be installed.

Can anyone recommend any decent Javascript client side libraries to do this?   If they're free, even nicer

Comment: As of 2016, good alternatives are [TechAn](https://github.com/andredumas/techan.js), [HighStock](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo), and perhaps [Plot.ly](https://plot.ly/highcharts-alternative/).

Comment: We provide a javascript library for stock charts at https://pizzacharts.com/charting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about using [Google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) itself. See an [example](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/candlestickchart.html#Example) or even [play around](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#candlestick_chart) with it.

Though this has one drawback - [you cannot use it offline](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/faq.html#offline). See [FAQ's](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/faq.html) for detail.

Google's [Annotated Time Line](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html) probably would meet your needs.

You may want to explore [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) as well. It's open source and looks pretty powerful.

Comment: Both Annotated Time Line and dygraphs look perfect.   Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for dygraphs! It never came up on Google, and it is perfect!

Answer (score 6):

http://www.highcharts.com/ is free for non-commercial use.

http://g.raphaeljs.com/ is completely free, based on the Raphael library, but comes with no documentation so you'll need to read through the source code of the examples.

Answer (score 4):

So... what's wrong with commercial?  I use commercial stuff all the time, because for larger projects, I have somebody to yell at when things don't work.

To that end, my recommendation for charting without plugins is always [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).  I have yet yo see anything else that approaches it for power, flexibility, but most important... something that works well out of the box (unlike, say Plotr or Raphaeljs).

Comment: nothing's wrong with commercial in principle..  but I don't have $4k in my pocket to spend on charting libraries, and the ones in my price range are not that great