# Creating a graph from JSON input

Tags: java, charts

I have queried yahoo finance for historic data and have got JSon output. What i would like to do is convert this JSon data into a graph. I am using java and would have to later upload this image into my mysql database. What is the best free library for creating charts(Line charts preferably). As i am new to this some tutorials on how to use will help .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get historic data using yahoo finance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936688/get-historic-data-using-yahoo-finance)

Comment: I'll add: please don't duplicate your own question.  If the existing answers aren't sufficient, edit the question to further specify what you need.

Comment: Take a look : http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/7995-how-plot-graph-java-given-samples.html http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090810035048AALpXQt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227421/good-javascript-library-for-drawing-charts-using-json

Comment: I would have to save this chart and upload it to my database. So just drawing it on a gui is not enough. Do you know any way to save it and upload it as a blob in mysql databse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using JFreeChart when building graphs in Java and it's a very powerful library.

Take a look at their site. 
http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [FusionCharts XT](http://fusioncharts.com/).

They work very well with Java - read their [docs](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?Code/J2EE/JSP_GettingStarted.html) for more info.

Their trial license works for unlimited duration, and has all the features as in the paid version.